# Cancel an async webrequest?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-ctp

I am using the Async CTP library for Windows Phone. Does anyone know how to cancel a pending webrequest?

```
Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_settings.Username, _settings.Password);
WebResponse resp;
try
{
    resp = await Request.GetResponseAsync();
}
```

There is no cancellation token (as specified in the [ASYNC Ctp tap document](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=19957)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try calling `Request.Abort()`.

Comment: Thanx, it tried your solution. If I call the Request.Abort() the opperation still continues, and after a while the Async throws an exception. I tried with a fake address (which eventually gives a timeout) and then cancel the request.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution. If I catch the WebException and check for the status, it gives me a RequestCancelled status. So this seems to be the way out! thnx.