# GetResponseAsync does not accept cancellationToken

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, async-await, httpwebresponse, cancellation-token

It seems that GetResponseAsync does not accept cancellationToken in Async/Await. So the question is how can I cancel the below procedure, provided I need to collect Cookies from response:

```
 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync())
 {
    cookies.Add(response.Cookies);
 }
```

An alternative code to achieve the above is also welcome.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Abort()`?

Comment: I've seen it in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635723/cancel-an-async-webrequest but not sure how to implement it correctly. I am passing the CancellationToken ct to the method.

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpClient`?

Comment: Well it seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage that it requires more code to write... Anyway why would you prefer HttpClient instead?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using (ct.Register(() => request.Abort(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
        {
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return (HttpWebResponse)response;
        }
    }
}
```

In theory, if cancellation is requested on `ct` and `request.Abort` is invoked, `await request.GetResponseAsync()` should throw a `WebException`. IMO though, it's always a good idea to check for cancellation explicitly when consuming the result, to mitigate race conditions, so I call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.

Also, I assume that `request.Abort` is thread-safe (can be called from any thread), so I use `useSynchronizationContext: false` (I haven't verified that).

**[UPDATED]** to address the OP's comment on how to differentiate between `WebException` caused by cancellation and any other error. This is how it can be done, so `TaskCanceledException` (derived from `OperationCanceledException`) will be correctly thrown upon cancellation:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using (ct.Register(() => request.Abort(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                return (HttpWebResponse)response;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // WebException is thrown when request.Abort() is called,
                // but there may be many other reasons,
                // propagate the WebException to the caller correctly
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // the WebException will be available as Exception.InnerException
                    throw new OperationCanceledException(ex.Message, ex, ct);
                }

                // cancellation hasn't been requested, rethrow the original WebException
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't this could be simplified further to `        public static async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(
            this HttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            using (ct.Register(request.Abort, false))
            {
                try
                {
                    return (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: @JosephLennox, you can do so, but you'd loose access to `WebException` in the client code, which is currently available as `Exception.InnerException` when cancellation is requested.

Comment: In Case this code reaches ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); i think var response should be closed.

Comment: @zirbel, you're right, `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` was racing there with a successful completion of `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync`. I removed the former, leaving it up to the caller to deal with this race condition (which still was there anyway, for when `Extensions.GetResponseAsync` possibly completes at the same time the token gets cancelled).

Answer (score 10):

```
public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action action, bool useSynchronizationContext = true)
{
    using (cancellationToken.Register(action, useSynchronizationContext))
    {
        try
        {
            return await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // the Exception will be available as Exception.InnerException
                throw new OperationCanceledException(ex.Message, ex, cancellationToken);
            }

            // cancellation hasn't been requested, rethrow the original Exception
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use your cancellation token on any cancelable async method. For example WebRequest.GetResponseAsync:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    . . .
}
```

will become:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync().WithCancellation(CancellationToken.None, request.Abort, true))
{
    . . .
}
```

See example http://pastebin.com/KauKE0rW