# Handling cancellation in Service Bus client

Tags: azure, async-await, azureservicebus

I'd like to use the Azure Service Bus client (Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll) in async mode, but am wondering how to handle cancellation. For example, the method `QueueClient.ReceiveAsync` does not take any `CancellationToken`, so considering that this method does not return as long as there is no message in the queue, how can I gracefully interrupt it if I want to take down the receiving loop?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question about `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19215782/1768303). While I'm not familiar with Azure Service Bus, I'd assume you could use `QueueClient.Abort` or `QueueClient.Close` where I used `HttpWebRequest.Abort`, so the pattern should remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will wait for some confirmation from someone familiar with SB before accepting the answer.