# c# abort async HttpWebRequest after timeout

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, cancellation-token

I found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19215782/4332018 a nice solution to use `CancellationToken` with `async HttpWebRequest`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using (ct.Register(() => request.Abort(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                return (HttpWebResponse)response;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // WebException is thrown when request.Abort() is called,
                // but there may be many other reasons,
                // propagate the WebException to the caller correctly
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // the WebException will be available as Exception.InnerException
                    throw new OperationCanceledException(ex.Message, ex, ct);
                }

                // cancellation hasn't been requested, rethrow the original WebException
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how I can abort `request` if it is performed longer than preset time.

I know about `CancellationTokenSource()` and `CancelAfter(Int32)`, but don't understand how to modify the above example to use `CancellationTokenSource`, because it hasn't `Register` method.

How can I make a `async HttpWebRequest` with the possibility of cancellation after preset time?

Comment: Why you don't use Timeout property of request ?

Comment: @MojtabaTajik i use proxy and have problems with use timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the token source, set the cancellation. Then pass in the token. It should timeout.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cts.CancelAfter(1000);

                var ct = cts.Token;

                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.zzz.com/here");
                var test = Extensions.GetResponseAsync(httpWebRequest, ct);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will be helpfull for you

```
 _cancelTasks = new CancellationTokenSource();
        string Response = null;
        var task = new Task(() => {

            try
            {
                using (var wb = new WebClient())
                {
                    var data = new NameValueCollection();
                    data["XMLString"] = XMLRequest;
                    var response = wb.UploadValues(ServiceURL, "POST", data);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }, _cancelTasks.Token);
        task.Start();
        if (!task.Wait(GWRequestTimeout * 1000))
        {

            _cancelTasks.Cancel();
        }
```