# Abort GetResponseAsync() and Exception in Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I have written a method which get `ETag` from eq. `XML` file on server. Am I correct wrote abort task if timeout (`GetResponseAsync()` doesn't have `CancellationToken`) and I have no other idea how to do `Exception`.

**Here's code:**

```
    public static async Task<string> GetETagAsync(Uri feedLink)
    {
        const int millisecondsTimeout = 2500;
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(feedLink);
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            Task<WebResponse> webResponse = webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            if (await Task.WhenAny(webResponse, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)) == webResponse)
            {
                using (var result = webResponse.Result)
                {
                    return result.Headers["ETag"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                webRequest.Abort();
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit**

I have made some changes. Rewrite exceptions and use class from this topic: [GetResponseAsync does not accept cancellationToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211972/getresponseasync-does-not-accept-cancellationtoken)

**Code:**

```
    public static async Task<string> GetETagAsync(Uri feedLink)
    {
        const int millisecondsTimeout = 2500;
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(feedLink);
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";

        try
        {
            Task<WebResponse> webResponse = WebRequestExtensions.GetResponseAsync(webRequest, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            if (await Task.WhenAny(webResponse, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)) == webResponse)
            {
                using (var result = webResponse.Result)
                {
                    return result.Headers["ETag"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is WebException)
                return null;

            throw;
        }
    }

public static class WebRequestExtensions
{
    public static async Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (cancellationToken.Register(() => request.Abort(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return (WebResponse)response;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    throw new TaskCanceledException(ex.Message, ex);
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct now?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to be catching all exceptions and returning `null`.  If you can't handle the exception, just let it propagate out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetResponseAsync does not accept cancellationToken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211972/getresponseasync-does-not-accept-cancellationtoken)

Comment: @Noseratio I read this, but I use `webRequest.Abort()` instead of your method and I want to know is it correct

Comment: @Servy I understand and agree but it's just method which can minimize data transfer. And actually only exception (and only once) I get was from site http://niebezpiecznik.pl there was something that "server refuse connection(?)" I don't remember what was exactly.

Comment: @J.Marciniak That doesn't mean you should just swallow the exceptions and pretend they don't exist.  When there's a problem you want to *know about it* rather than having your code break further down the line without being able to understand why.

Comment: @J.Marciniak, did you not notice `request.Abort()` in [the code there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19215782/1768303)? You can call `request.Abort()` from outside, too.

Comment: @Noseratio you're right, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @Servy edit first post ;)

Comment: @J.Marciniak I was dealing with this in a polling service, and what you have is essentially what I have, but in a loop, with one critical difference.    That difference is that I abort the request every time.  I have not copy/pasted your code to test it, but it should work for the first attempt, and the second, assuming it's within some window - maybe the default (non-async) `GetResponse()` of 100000ms?  But eventually your `Task.WhenAny` will start returning the `Task.Delay` every time. Right now I don't know exactly why it fails on successive attempts.

Comment: @J.Marciniak I think it has to do with the async response stream left pending.  If you are not going to read the response stream until the end, then you should call `request.Abort()` regardless of whether the task completed before the `Task.Delay` or not.  If you do not abort (or read until the end of the stream maybe, haven't tried this) future `Tasks` involving `GetResponseAsync()` will sit in a waiting status until after the `Task.Delay` completes.  Yes, the extension method will call `Abort()`, but I think you want to also call it after reading the critical data from the response.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `WebRequestExtensions` class I wrote here to resolve the problem:
https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/master/src/corelib/Core/WebRequestExtensions.cs

This class fully supports both a `CancellationToken` and the `WebRequest.Timeout` property.

Comment: I read this: but not sure is it correct [Cancel an async webrequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635723/cancel-an-async-webrequest)

Comment: @J.Marciniak I'm not sure how that relates to my answer?

Comment: it seems `GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request)` has been added to the MVC code, but not `GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Since the method doesn't natively support any means of stopping the task, it can't be stopped.  There is nothing that you can do that will prevent it from continuing to do whatever it plans to do.  What you *can* do is ensure that this async method's task doesn't wait for it to finish.  While you can just return a value, as you're doing, this seems to represent an exceptional case; you should probably be throwing an exception to indicate that the operation timed out.